# Downcasting and upcasting objects and dynamic method binding

Tags: java

When I do `account1.equals(account2)` I have to downcast account2 in the `equals()` method back to its subclass reference `BankAccount compareAccount = (BankAccount)obj;` so that I have access to the child classes fields. Once I downcast it, then I can do `compareAccount.accountAmount`

So now for my question

However in this script I didnt need to do downcast the account1 object to use its fields in the `equals()` method. I thought since I had upcasted it to object `Object account1 = new BankAccount(300.22, 122222)` I would not be able to see its fields and therefore, `this.accountAmount` would not work until I downcasted back to the childclass. **So why is this, why does it account1 not need to be downcasted?**

```
public class BankAccountDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Object account1 = new BankAccount(300.22, 122222);
        Object account2 = new BankAccount(333.10, 23432434);

        if(account1.equals(account2))
        {
            System.out.println("The objects are equals");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("These objects are not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Object class

```
public class BankAccount
{
    private double accountAmount;
    private int accountNumber;

    public BankAccount(double accountAmount, int accountNumber)
    {
        this.accountAmount = accountAmount;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        BankAccount compareAccount = (BankAccount)obj;
        boolean result;
        if (this.accountAmount == compareAccount.accountAmount && this.accountNumber   == compareAccount.accountNumber)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the parameter type of  the single parameter of the `equals` method?

Comment: Why are you making them `Object`'s?

Comment: The type of `this` is `BankAccount`, not `Object`.

Comment: As a side not, your `BankAccount#equals` violates the [contract for `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) . [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) is worth reviewing.

Comment: *"However in this script I didnt need to do downcast the account1 object to use its fields in the equals() method."*  --  You do not need to "downcast" an object to a supertype to use that types method. They are inherited by all derived classes. So you can use `.equals(Object)` on every instance of every class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that simply the equals method of `BankAccount` is called. Therefore, this method has naturally access to all the class' members.

The equals method of `BankAccount` is called in

```
Object account1 = new BankAccount(300.22, 122222);
Object account2 = new BankAccount(333.10, 23432434);
if(account1.equals(account2)) { … }
```

because methods are always virtual, such that the `equals` method of the instance's type of `account1` (`BankAccount`) is called - not the declared type (`Object`).

However, you should consider re-thinking your design. Search for explanations how `equals` should be written.
In particular, only cast the parameter to `BankAccount` after you have assured that it is `instanceof BankAccount` or at least that BankAccount is [assignable from](https://www.ralfebert.de/archive/java/isassignablefrom/) the object's class.